# Make elements stay in same position without wrapping

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Thanks in advance for your help. I have created a navigation bar, complete with social widgets and page links. I would like the words within that list and the social widgets to stay in the same position, rather than wrap when the browser resizes or zooms in. You can refer to JSfiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/kadeemlaurie/KGwWV/

This is the HTML:

```
 <div id="header-menu-wrap"> 
 <div id="header-menu">
 <div id="header-menu-items">
 <span class="menu-item-fake"></span>

  <a class="menu-item active" href="/">
   <span class="mi-wrap">
    <span class="hmi-label">+Home</span>  
     <span class="mi-arrow"></span></span></a>

  <a class="menu-item active" href="/">
   <span class="mi-wrap">
    <span class="hmi-label">Blog</span>  
     <span class="mi-arrow"></span>
      </span>
       </a>

  <div class="menu-item">
   <span class="mi-wrap">
    <span class="home-icon" data-icon="D"></span>
    <span class="hmi-label">Events</span>  
    <span class="mi-arrow"></span></span>

  <div class="submenu-item">
   <div class="submenu-content">
    <span class="submenu-hit-area"></span>
    <canvas class="submenu-triangle" width="20" height="11"></canvas>
    <ul class="drop-menu-list">

  <li>
   <a class="parent-category-lnk" href="/category/css">Maison X IESOGEN</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
      </div></div></div>

  <a class="menu-item" href="/category/freebies">
   <span class="mi-wrap">
    <span class="home-icon" data-icon="o"></span>
     <span class="hmi-label">About</span></span>
      </a>


 <span class="menu-item-fake"></span></div></form></div>      

  <div id="header-socials">
   <span id="share-post-label">Share: </span>
    <span class="fb-home-btn" style="width: 80px;">

  <a class="fb-stub" href="#" target="_blank" 
   data-shares="100" send="false" layout="button_count" width="70"  
   show_faces="true">Like

 <span class="fb-stub-arr"></span></a></span>
 <span class="twitter-home-btn">

 <a data-shares="90" class="tw-stub" style="margin-right:45px" href="#"     
 target="_blank">Tweet>

 <span class="tw-stub-ico"></span> <span class="tw-stub-arr"></span></a></span>
 </div></div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
  margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px
    }

    .rounded{
      -moz-border-radius: 4px; /* Firefox */
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px; /* Safari, Chrome */
      border-radius: 4px; /* CSS3 */
      behavior: url(border-radius.htc);}

    .border{border:solid px;}
    .dark{border-color:#000;}
    .olive{background-color:#fff;}

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2,fo h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, tr {

     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: none;
     outline: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     vertical-align: baseline;
     background: transparent;
     text-decoration: none;}

    body {font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; 
    font-size:13px; position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; top:0; min-height:100%;
    line-height: 16px;
    background:#232323;}

    h1{ font-size:13px;  font-weight:bold; font-family: 'Arial', 'helvetica' 'sans-serif';}


    #header-socials { float:right; margin:9px 160px 0 0 ;}
    #share-post-label { height:auto;  margin:0px 5px 0 0; position:relative; top:2px; } 
    #header-socials span {vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block;        
    height:21px;color:fff;}


    #nav-bar-close-link { position:absolute;  
    top:8px; right:20px; 
    font-size:28px; text-decoration:none;
    line-height:28px;
    display:none;
    color:#666;}

    #nav-bar-close-link:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#999;}

    #header-wrap {height:302px; }
    #header-menu-wrap {background: #232323; height:30px;  position:fixed; z-index:20;   
    width:100%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}

    #header-menu-wrap:hover {overflow:visible;} #header-menu {margin:0 auto; 
    max-width:1284px; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 
    sans-serif;}

    .header-menu-section { position:relative; margin-right:20px; height:30px;       
    display:block; float:left; text-align:center; /*border-right:1px solid #999;*/
    z-index:7;}

    #main-menu-select { display:none;}
    #mbl-wrap { display:none;}
    #header-menu-items {margin: -4 0 0 121;}
    #header-menu .menu-item:hover {text-decoration:none;  }

    #header-menu .menu-item:hover .mi-wrap{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

    #header-menu .menu-item, .menu-item-fake {
    display: inline-block; height:30px; padding:0px 15px; float:left;
    color: #ccc; position:relative; z-index:auto;}

   .submenu-item {position:absolute; top:-9999px; left:0px; z-index:1;}

    a.parent-category-lnk {color:#ccc; font-size:14px; display:block;  padding:8px 20px; 
    white-space:nowrap;}
   .submenu-item li { display:block; border-bottom:1px solid #4C4C4C; }
   .submenu-item li:last-child { border:none;}
   .submenu-item li:hover { background:#4C4C4C; text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px black;}


   .mi-wrap {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:auto;
    top:10px;    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#ccc; text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000;}


    .mi-arrow { font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle; position:relative; top:0px;}

    .menu-item-fake:first-child {border-left:none; padding:0;}
    .menu-item-fake:last-child {border-right:none;  padding-right:0;}

    #md-deal-wdd-block #md-large-widget-content, #md-deal-wdd-block {text-align:center;     
    position:relative;}


    #header-content-wrap {margin:0 auto; height:108px;  position:relative; background: 
    url(http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/themes/wdd_new/css-images/head-tile.png);}
    #header-content {position:relative; z-index:2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1140px;}

    #header-socials #___plusone_0{ width:70px !important; }
#header-socials .fb-home-btn { margin-right:5px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 878px)  {
  #header-socials {display:none;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1376px)  {
  #top_link { display:none !important;}
  #nav-bar-close-link { right:5px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1342px)  {
 #nav-bar-close-link { display:none !important;}
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1164px)  {
  #nav-bar-close-link { display:none !important;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
#header-wrap { /*height:100px;*/ height:55px; position:relative; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}

   #header-menu { text-align:center;}



    #header-menu-items { display:none;}


}

 /* SOCIAL WIDGETS STUBS */
.fb-stub {

-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #CAD4E7;
cursor: pointer;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #3B5998 !important;
padding: 1px 5px 1px 20px;
display: inline-block;
font-size:11px;
font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-weight:normal !important;
background:#ECEEF5 url('http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yI/x/1dQf_ATK831.png') no-repeat 4px 2px;
position: relative;
margin-right:28px;
}    


.fb-stub:hover { border-color:#9DACCE; text-decoration: none !important;}

.fb-stub::before, .tw-stub::before {
  content: attr(data-shares);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
  color:#333 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  min-width: 15px;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  cursor:default;
}   


.fb-stub-arr, .tw-stub-arr {
border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;

 position: absolute;
 border-color: transparent #D7D7D7 transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 4px 5px 4px 0;
 display: block;
 top:5px; left:100%;

 margin-left:2px;
 height:0px !important;

}

.tw-stub-arr::after,
.fb-stub-arr::after{
  content:'';
 border-color: transparent #D7D7D7 transparent;
 border-right-color: white;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 4px 5px 4px 0;
display: block;
position: absolute;
left:2px;
top:-4px;
}


.tw-stub {
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  zoom: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;

  position: relative;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(white),to(#DEDEDE));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white,#DEDEDE);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,white,#DEDEDE);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,white,#DEDEDE);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,white,#DEDEDE);
border: #CCC solid 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;

text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
cursor: pointer;

font: normal normal normal 11px/18px 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
padding:0px 5px 0px 20px;

}

.tw-stub:hover, .tw-stub:active {
  text-decoration: none !important;
border-color: #BBB;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#F8F8F8),to(#D9D9D9));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#F8F8F8,#D9D9D9);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#F8F8F8,#D9D9D9);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#F8F8F8,#D9D9D9);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#F8F8F8,#D9D9D9);
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;}

.tw-stub::before{
background: white;
border: #BBB solid 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
min-width: 8px;
font-weight: normal;
}

.twitter-btn-wrap .tw-stub::before { display:none;}
.twitter-btn-wrap .tw-stub {margin-right:0;} 

.tw-stub-ico{
  width:16px; height:13px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-5px;
  left:2px;
  background: url('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/images/btn.27237bab4db188ca749164efd38861b0.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
}



/*one column here*/

#container
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
    background:#fff;
    height:900;
}

#header
{
    background:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#header h1 { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: What would you like to happen when the browser becomes to small to fit all the information? Have it be unaccessible? Personally, wrapping seems like the ideal way to preserve functionality on smaller devices.

Comment: Hello @bookcasey as you can see the social buttons and page links disappear when the browser is resized. Ideally, I would want the page links to be functional on smaller devices but to still stay in the same position. But if it would be possible, it would be nice for all the elements to be functional.

Comment: But what will happen—say—when the links staying in the same place take up 600px, but the viewport is 400px? If they don't wrap, where do they go?

Comment: That's true, I'll probably go with what you recommended then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `inline-block`:

```
.cntranav ul{
  white-space: nowrap;    
}

.cntranav li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGwWV/1/)

Or add `overflow: hidden` to the `ul`. Note with this technique, elements that don't fit disappear instead of being half shown.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGwWV/2/)

However, I would not recommend either. Either allow wrapping or use `@media` queries to ensure that the navigation is always visible no matter how small the viewport.

Comment: Sorry mate, gave the wrong JFiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/kadeemlaurie/rX2dX/ I'll give them a try now though.